# Is there a similar WFP method to filter beacons and access point handshakes?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, traffic-filtering

I have been studying [Windows Filtering Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page) and I can make basic Firewalls with it with windows, but I can only filter Ipv4, Ipv6, and specific ports for example. I want to do the same for connecting to access points, I want to code wpa2 handshake from scratch at driver level.

https://patents.google.com/patent/CN102195972B/en this patent of google shows how to use Windows Filtering Platform to filter packets when **connected** to a network I want to do this for access points. Which layer I need to use for that, or which specific functions of [WFP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/windows-filtering-platform-start-page) if there is any

Or this can also help.. wpa2 handshake coding requires which library ? https://www.komodia.com/ndis may i create a virtual access point with Network Driver Interface Specification ? (Note: I will not use any AI generation)

**Found Link for NDIS documentation on windows**

https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/driver__ndis_8c.html

I see a function named, `void     wpa_driver_ndis_event_connect (struct wpa_driver_ndis_data *drv)`

Is this an event logger or is it what does the connection for NDIS ? Is there any example of usage of this function, hence I want to connect wpa2 at driver level but I can't find any example code functions.

I also found [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant/+/6eb6225dda14c6eaf34fcb3498e17d28060e1e16/driver_ndis.c) from android.. Can someone break it down in parts and explain it to me ?

Edit:

I installed winpcap 4.1 on xp which includes ndis 5, but i cant find 32 bit mingw32 that has headers to build driver with. (I need mingw) also after winpcap installation, gcc driver_ndis.c -lwinpcap be enough for compile?

Comment: WFP is primarily Layer 3 and above, so if you want to filter Layer 2 data grams you will probably have to use the NDIS interface. that is of course if this isn;t an AI-generated question. its particularly odd to reference a patent, rather than a specification document or somesuch.

Comment: Linked the NDIS doc @FrankThomas Yes it is an odd reference haha..

Comment: if i wanted to code virtual access point.. wpa2 from scratch, would ndis be enough ? do i need drivers for that ? @FrankThomas

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. you are getting not only into the programming realm (where I am comfortable) but also into the Driver+kernel level programming realm (where I am not). I just know that the only Layer2 interface WFP provides is the NDIS integration. beyond that i won;t be of too much help.